# Unable to draw on canvas HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to include a canvas element within a form where the user can draw their signature. The border and box is created but when I attempt to draw on it, nothing happens. The strokes seem to be created fine when I put the code defining the canvas tag outside the form tag. Below is my code, any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<form>
<label for="idate" style="display:block">Issue Date:</label> 
<input type="text" id="idate" name="idate"> </span>

<input name="name" placeholder="Your name" required />

<canvas id="signature" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("signature");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var drawing = false;
var prevX, prevY;
var currX, currY;
var signature = document.getElementsByName('signature')[0];

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start);

function start() {
drawing = true;
}

function stop() {
drawing = false;
prevX = prevY = null;
signature.value = canvas.toDataURL();
}

function draw(e) {
if (!drawing) {
return;
}
currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
if (!prevX && !prevY) {
prevX = currX;
prevY = currY;
}

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

prevX = currX;
prevY = currY;
}

function onSubmit(e) {
console.log({
'name': document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value,
'signature': signature.value,
 });
 return false;
 }
 </script>

<input type="hidden" name="signature" />

<button type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in here `var canvas = document.getElementById("signature');`

It should be like this `var canvas = document.getElementById("signature");`

You opened the string with `"` and close it with `'`. To avoid this kind of errors, consider using good code editor. For instance, **Visual Studio Code**.

Your fixed code:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<form>
<label for="idate" style="display:block">Issue Date:</label> 
<input type="text" id="idate" name="idate"> </span>

<input name="name" placeholder="Your name" required />

<canvas id="signature" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("signature"); // here was the syntax error
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var drawing = false;
var prevX, prevY;
var currX, currY;
var signature = document.getElementsByName('signature')[0];

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start);

function start() {
drawing = true;
}

function stop() {
drawing = false;
prevX = prevY = null;
signature.value = canvas.toDataURL();
}

function draw(e) {
if (!drawing) {
return;
}
currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
if (!prevX && !prevY) {
prevX = currX;
prevY = currY;
}

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

prevX = currX;
prevY = currY;
}

function onSubmit(e) {
console.log({
'name': document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value,
'signature': signature.value,
 });
 return false;
 }
 </script>

<input type="hidden" name="signature" />

<button type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I am not sure why, but you try to assign a dataURI to HTML element. Consider this

```js
var signature; // no need to select canvas element, just save dataURI in this variable

function stop() {
  drawing = false;
  prevX = prevY = null;
  signature = canvas.toDataURL();
}

function onSubmit(e) {
console.log({
'name': document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value,
'signature': signature,
 });
 return false;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I've corrected the syntax error but it doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: I've used a dataURI so when you stop drawing, it will get saved as an image

Comment: It does resolve the issue, with the corrected syntax, I am able to draw shapes on canvas. And about the error with value not being defined check the code with the dataURI that I provided too

Comment: Thanks, it does work as you say. I posted the code without the css, which seems to prevent me from drawing